# JIRA: Update sprint status using python-jira lib

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Im' try to create a periodic task that close a print and launch the next.

What I'm planning to do is to find the current Sprint ("state":"ACTIVE") and update its state to ("state":"CLOSED") and take the next Sprint and update it from FUTURE to ACTIVE in a bi-weekly basis.

I can see in the library that we can not update the state of a sprint (this part is commented by default):

```
def update_sprint(self, id, name=None, startDate=None, endDate=None):
    payload = {}
    if name:
        payload['name'] = name
    if startDate:
        payload['startDate'] = startDate
    if endDate:
        payload['startDate'] = endDate
    # if state:
    #    payload['state']=state

    url = self._get_url('sprint/%s' % id, base=self.AGILE_BASE_URL)
    r = self._session.put(
        url, data=json.dumps(payload))

    return json_loads(r)
```

My questions is:

Is there a reason for this?

How can I perform this operation in another way ?

Thanks!

**Update**

I raised a bug and it has been fixed:
https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/123

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

after login to Jira

```
self.jira = JIRA(server='server', basic_auth=(self.jira_user, self.jira_apikey))
```

you can update sprint by providing all sprint data :

```
response = self.jira.update_sprint(id=294, name='name', state='active', startDate=datetime(2023, 6, 24).isoformat(), endDate=datetime(2023, 7, 15).isoformat())
```

so to change the status simply change the 'state' value

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure how you are updating your values but the way I have been updating values is:

```
    issue.update(status={'name': 'Closed'})
```

Source: http://pythonhosted.org/jira/

Comment: Op is talking about sprints, not issues.